# I have a folder that contains multiple folders which contain images. I want to filter the images based on dimensions

Tags: powershell

This code displays the ImageName and FolderName properly, but the Dimension remains blank.And the data which is displayed properly is not getting saved in a csv file.

Also, If condition based on dimension is not working.

```
#-----------powershell script------------
foreach ($folder in $Folders) { 
    $Images = Get-ChildItem  -Path $Folder -Filter *.png
    $Results = @()
    foreach ($image  in $Images) { 
        $dimensions = $image.Dimensions
        # $dimensions = "$($image.Width) x $($image.Height)"
        If ($dimensions -ne '1000 x 1000') {


            $Results += [pscustomobject]@{
                ImageName  = $image
                FolderName = $Folder
                Dimension  = $dimensions
            }
        }
    }



    $Results | FT -auto

    # $ExcelData= Format-Table -property @{n="$image";e='$Folder'}
    $Results | Export-csv "C:\Users\M1036098\Documents\Imagelessthan1000pi.txt" -NoTypeInformation

}
```

Dimension property in output remains blank

Comment: Why do you expect `Dimensions` property to be set?

Answer (score 2):

So lets go over why this doesnt work. `Get-ChildItem` brings back the Object `System.Io.FileInfo`

[System.IO.FileIonfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8) we can see from Microsoft there is no method or property named Dimensions.

So then lets get those dimensions...

First we are going to load the image into memory and get the size.

```
$Folders = @("C:\Test")

$Folders | %{
    $Folder = $_
    Get-ChildItem  -Path $_ -Filter *.png | %{
        try{
            $Image = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap "$($_.FullName)"
            [pscustomobject]@{
                ImageName  = $_.Name
                FolderName = $Folder
                Dimension  = "$($Image.Height) x $($Image.Width)"
            }
        }catch{
        }
    } | ?{
        $_.Dimension -ne "1000 x 1000"
    }
}
```

Output looks like

```
ImageName     FolderName     Dimension  
---------     ----------     ---------  
Test1.png     C:\Test        1440 x 2560
Test2.png     C:\Test        1200 x 1200
```

Edit : Adding function for Sonam. Based on a answer that was posted.

```
function Get-ImageDimension([string]$Path, [array]$ImageExtensions, [array]$ExcludeDimensions){

    Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Include $ImageExtensions -Recurse | foreach-object{
        try{
            $image = [Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_);
            [pscustomobject]@{
                ImageName = $_.Name
                FolderName = $_.DirectoryName
                Dimension= "$($image.Width) x $($image.Height)"
            }
        }catch{
        }
    } | ?{
        $ExcludeDimensions -notcontains $_.Dimension
    }
}


Get-ImageDimension C:\Test\ -ImageExtensions *.png -ExcludeDimensions "1000 x 1000" | export-csv C:\Test\Test.csv
```

Comment: Hi, I rewrote the code using System.Drawing.
Code Snippet:

Comment: Please Take a look at the rewritten code below and give your insights. I was not able to put the code in comment box, so have put it in answer section.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution. I rewrote the code using System.Drawing.
    Code Snippet:

```
try{
    $FolderBase= "E:\D\Demo\Demo\"
    $Folders= get-ChildItem "$FolderBase*" |

    foreach ($folder in $Folders){ 

        $Images=Get-ChildItem  -Path $Folder -Filter *.png
        $Results = @()

        #$image=(Get-ChildItem  -Path $Folder *.png)
        $Images | ForEach-Object { 
            $img = [Drawing.Image].FromFile($_); 
            $dimensions = "$($img.Width) x $($img.Height)"

            If ($dimensions -ne "1000 x 1000") {
                $Results +=  [pscustomobject]@{
                    ImageName = $img
                    FolderName = $Folder
                    Dimension= $dimensions
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $Results | FT -auto
    # $ExcelData= Format-Table -property @{n="$image";e='$Folder'}
    $Results|Export-csv "C:\Users\****\Documents\Imagelessthan1000pi.txt" -NoTypeInformation
}catch{
}
```

Now, I get the desired results but

1. I am not able to write the data to a file.(excel (preferred),csv,text). I tried out-File and Export-csv.
2. One of the folder contains a large no of big size(700 kb max) images. and while executing the loop on that particular folder,
   memory exception is thrown and it does not loop through all the
   images.

Comment: You need to pipe more. Powershell is about piping. Try to avoid `Foreach` and instead use `Foreach-Object` whos alias is `%`. Also try to avoid `IF` in favor of `Where-Object` who alias is `?`. I will rewrite your script so it works.

Comment: Actually now that i look over it in more detail you have alot wrong.First you are making an assuming that `Get-ChildItem` will return folders. `Get-ChildItem` returns all files and folders when run like you have. Second off the `try` is on the outside meaning any errors and you cant get any files. Also you had a extra `}` in the script so it would fail anyways. You also are tyring to pipe a `Foreach` instead of a `foreach-object`.

Comment: Added a function in my answer for you to use easier